# Hibernate database migration - merging duplicate entities

Tags: java, hibernate

**Premise**:

I have been recently assigned to work with a Java + JPA + Hibernate application.

This application has 4 different "modules" and each is a "copy+paste" of each other, with minor changes.

I want to remove all duplications and work with a single database schema (currently, there is one schema for each "module").

I am trying to start in the least "invasive" way, not changing too much of what's already there.

What I did was:

- I created a base module and moved some hibernate entities there.
- I made these entities abstract and created implementations for each module.
- I create a new schema and moved every other module record to it (I had to disable the database constraints for now).

Example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SYSTEM", length = 10, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "GROUP")
public abstract class Group<U extends UserGroup> {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "group")
    private List<U> users;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_GROUP")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SYSTEM", length = 10, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class UserGroup<G extends Group> {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private G group;
```

The implementations just define a discriminator column.

**Issue**:

The following query:

```
public interface UserGroupRepository<T extends UserGroup> extends CrudRepository<T, Integer> {


    @Query(value = "select grp.code from #{#entityName} ug join ug.group grp where ug.name= ?1")
    Iterable<String> listGroupByUser(String name);
```

Is returning 4 items because my user has a record for each module in the database (it should return only 1 item).

**Question**:

Using "@Query", can I somehow filter by the discriminator value properly?

Answer (score 0):

According to Hibernate [Inheritance doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html), you can get this by `table per subclass` instead of `table per class hierarchy` strategy.

Comment: I am avoiding changing the queries and mappings too much, but your answer gave me something to think about. In this particular scenario, with copy and pasted entities, repositories and everything else too, what could be a good refactoring strategy to simplify it? It is all a single application, and the previous dev had some time constraints so he just copied everything and changed a bit. I believe it could all be together in the same entities, just with some discriminator column. i.e. "Give me the user groups for app=X", "Give me the user groups for app=Y" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try using the where clause. There is a special class property that you can use to restrict a query to a subtype. Below is the hibernate reference documentation.

[image: hibernate reference doc.]

In your case you can use the subEntity name instead of DomesticCat.

[Click](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where) here to see the hibernate documentation of the where clause.

Comment: There is no "magic" way to do this without setting the class explicitly, right? For example, in my query "select grp.code from #{#entityName} ug join ug.group grp where ug.name= ?1", could it have something like "select grp.code from #{#entityName} ug join ug.group grp where ug.name= ?1 AND 'group is of the type defined in the mapping of the UserGroup'"?